# Identify partially built LEGO set

Tags: set-identification

Can anyone help me identify what LEGO set this is from?  My son has it half built and we cannot find the instructions and the bricks have been mixed with his other LEGO.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is all from one set? I cannot seem to find a set that contains both [Wedge 6x2 Inverted Left](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=41765&in=S) in Light (Bluish) Gray, [Wedge 4x2 Sloped Left](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=43721&in=S) in White as well as [Technic, Brick Modified 2 x 2 with Pin Hole, Rotation Joint Ball Half (Horizontal Top), Rotation Joint Socket](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=47452&in=S) in Dark (Bluish) Gray.

Comment: Oh and one more observation corroborating my previous statement - even though the picture is of very bad quality, it seems to me that the front part and the two 1x6 bricks in the back are of a different color gray than the rest - which leads me to think that you have a mix of Dark Gray and Dark Bluish Gray in this build, which would not have happened in the same LEGO set.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the different shades of gray and the odd placement of the ball joint, I believe this is not a Lego set. Its more likely that it is something your son made out of his imagination and other Lego pieces.

Answer (score -1):

I personally don't think this is lego. I've seen some of the elements in the pictures in Kre-o battleships sets. Perhaps you can evaluate on that?

Comment: These all exist as Lego parts. I see no reason to assume they are not Lego. :/